# javascript regex: replacing non youtube embeds

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I'm trying to write a simple regex that will locate object tags and ignore any matches that contain the words "youtube or "youtu.be".

I've tried

```
<object .*?>.+?(?=youtube|youtu\.be).+?<\/object>
```

Which successfully locates object tags WITH those words in them, but the converse does not work and instead just returns all object matches.

```
<object .*?>.+?(?!youtube|youtu\.be).+?<\/object>
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

EDIT:
It has to look through a source similar to:

```html
fdgfdgfdg
<object width="560" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/-F_ke3rxopc?version=3&amp;hl=en_US">
    </param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    </param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    </param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-F_ke3rxopc?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
    </embed>
</object>
fdgfdgdg
<object width="400" height="300">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=31589401&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" />
    <embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=31589401&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="400" height="300">
    </embed>
</object>
fdgdgg
```

Then pick out object blocks that do not contain the words so than I can run a replace on them.

Comment: When picking a solution remember that the URL to a non-youtube embed could easily include `&youtube=false` or any number of ways to get the string 'youtube' in there.

Answer (score 0):

a valid but not perfect regex would be:

```
<object.*>.*(youtube|youtu\.be).*<\/object>
```

btw. http://www.rubular.com/ is a nice website to check regular expressions